# HTML Table data displaying as text then as table

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

I have a data driven table that is produced server-side with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <style type = "text/css">
    table {border: 1px solid black;}
    td {border: 1px solid black;}
  </style>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
          <td>...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is in all three browsers (IE, FF, Chrome) the data renders first as bunched up text and the the table renders with the data in it.  I do a view source and all I see is the html in the format above, but the bunched up text in the beginning is not there.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I probably need to clarify, but the table itself renders great, however it's underneath all of the text.  The text is a copy of what is in the table, just not formatted in any way.  It's not even supposed to be there.

Comment: Are you sure your markup is valid. When you right-click and inspect the resulting tree of elements, does it reflect what you authored in your markup? Access to a live demo would be very helpful.

Comment: my first suggestion woulf be to use the style table-layout: fixed; though I doubt it will make a difference. any chance of a live example?

Comment: You should clarify the question by editing the question itself. It should be fully understandable without peeking at any comments. And the code posted does not illustrate the problem at all. You need to show an example that actually *has* a problem.

Comment: Most likely the `style` tag between `head` and `body` causes the issue. Move it to the `head`, hence it would be parsed when the `body` begins.

Comment: The code posted IS the code that I have. Why would I post some other code that you think I should post?  Anyway, thanks for the info everybody, I'll continue to work on this to see if I can figure it out on my own.